# What are the rules regarding obtaining consent from subjects when publishing results related to drug testing?

Tags: research-process, ethics, medicine, france

I am wondering what the rules relative to consent of subjects are for publishing results related to drug testing.

[This recent publication](https://doi.org/10.1002/dta.3164) by private lab researchers reports the result of drug testing on seven cyclists on hair samples collected by the police.

> During an international 3-week cyclist race in France, a special public health division of the police [inspected] a whole team. In addition to the control of the rooms and the medical devices and products by the police, a trained forensic pathologist was requested to collect head hair specimens from seven cyclists. ... This was a target request from the judge based on suspicion as numerous boxes of tizanidine were found in the room of the medical doctor of the team.

However, the paper makes no mention of the cyclists' consent in having their hair used for research, or of any approval by an ethics board. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: One would need to know what professional cyclists agree to in order to participate. Likely it includes use of any samples for anti-doping research.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- am wondering what the rules of consent are for publications related to drug testing.  I would have thought consent of subjects is necessary, and that it would be stated in the publication.

Comment: A [previous paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570023220313714?via%3Dihub#s0010), on a similar subject, by the same authors (+1 more) says 'Given it was a personal request of the athlete, the test was not relevant for any ethical review committee'.

Comment: @DanielHatton In this paper, samples were obtained during a police raid

Comment: @MisterMak Yes, so we know that the specific ethical justification for the newer paper must be different, but the statement in the previous paper at least tells us the authors are aware that there's such a thing as ethical review of research proposals, and that it's potentially relevant to studies of this type.

Comment: @JonCuster I can imagine a university ethics committee taking the view that, if a participant has to consent as a condition of keeping their job, that consent is not sufficiently free and informed to be valid.

Comment: @DanielHatton - professional sports and anti-doping are likely handled quite differently from standard workplace agreements. And has been shown many times over the decades, national governments are broadly in support of (legally, monetarily, ...) efforts to combat doping. Note that in the abstract to the paper (the only part I could access), the study was requested by the French police. That professional athletes will be drug-tested and punished if in violation is well known, and even amateur athletes are tested from an early age.

Comment: @JonCuster I tracked down the [WADA Doping Control Form](https://www.wada-ama.org/sites/default/files/resources/files/doping_control_form_v12_0.pdf), which contains an _optional_ consent checkbox for the use of samples in research.  But I'm guessing the French Public Health Police probably don't use the same form as WADA.

Comment: @DanielHatton - I guess the question would be, did the study go through IRB approval or not? Without access to the full paper I can't tell...

Comment: @JonCuster I don't have access to the full paper either, but I can probe its contents with Google Scholar searches, and it doesn't contain the words "ethics", "ethical", or "irb".

Comment: Under the WADA guidelines (https://www.wada-ama.org/sites/default/files/resources/files/ispppi_guidelinesforprivacy_final_sept2021.pdf), permissible 'anti-doping activities' that use personal information includes 'Anti-doping research'.

Comment: I updated the Q to what I think you'd like to ask. Feel free to edit if I missed the mark.

Comment: Note the weird use of "controlled" by the authors - I suspect this is a translation error, but I don't know what they meant.

Comment: In the last few days, a cycling team has issued an angry-sounding [press release](https://bahraincyclingteam.com/bahrain-victorious-respond-to-hair-sample-report/) about the paper.

Comment: @JonCuster and Daniel I do have access, and it has no reference whatsoever.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- The French word "contrôlé" can mean "inspected", which seems to fit the context.

Comment: Indeed, it is called (loosely translated) 'drug control' when you get tested. So we have the police providing samples - did they provide any PII or was the lab just reporting on the ability to measure a given drug in unassociated-to-a-person samples. And would a normal IRB sign off on something like that? Way out of my league. Perhaps better a question to the journal about the required standards to publish there.

Comment: @JonCuster 'did they provide any PII or was the lab just reporting on the ability to measure a given drug in unassociated-to-a-person samples'  For anyone who follows road cycling, the information in the paragraph that Azor has edited into the question is enough to identify who the seven cyclists are, although not, of course, which three were associated with the non-zero results.

Comment: @DanielHatton Was only one team inspected by police? You posted that it seems to be Bahrain (the paper later mentions all the hairs were brown/black). Is seven the entire team?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- If any other team was inspected, it was kept much quieter than the raid on Bahrain Victorious, which was discussed at length in the television commentary on the next day's stage.  The number 7 is also distinctive: a full Tour de France team consists of 8 riders, but one of BV's withdrew as a result of a crash earlier in the Tour.  And BV's press release certainly suggests that _they_ think the paper is about them.

Comment: If the samples are collected under a court order, is consent even relevant?

Comment: @mmeent The court order is likely to confer the right to collect and test the samples without worrying about consent, but rather less likely to confer the right to publish a research paper about the results without consent.

Comment: Incidentally, I just found [another paper from the same authors](https://www.mdpi.com/2305-6304/9/10/251/htm) which says 'Patient consent was waived due to the fact that biological specimens were collected during hospitalization with a purpose of toxicological diagnostic.'   That's dicey, right?

Comment: @DanielHatton It's normal to not get patient consent when using data already collected for another purpose. There's no harm to the patient from collecting the data in that case; it's really rare to do any sort of retroactive consent unless there's a new data collection step (eg, retrospective data on a particular surgery, but you want to contact patients to do a 90d follow up). An IRB would decide whether there is harm from making the data itself public, which is substantially mitigated if the data are anonymized, and may not require any sort of consent.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- updates to question appreciated, have added a minor one myself.

Comment: @DanielHatton Others have cautioned about trying to ID the team; there was only one month between the police raid this year and submission of the article; and there have been similar raids previous years.

Comment: @MisterMak  Good point: if we look back beyond 2021, the description is not uniquely identifying.

Answer (score 3):

Rules for this sort of thing come from two sources: institutions and publishers; there is no central body for research ethics, though there can be national and international organizations that choose to publish guidelines. There may also be country-specific laws (or at other levels of government), but ordinarily in my experience these are mostly administered at the institution level where the institution guidelines meet or exceed any legal standards, so an individual investigator can just comply with their institution and they'll be covered.

Most journals publishing in a (bio)medical area have some official statement that authors must provide assurance that some standard for research subjects protection is met. It's really up to the journal what their standard is and what they will publish. In some jurisdictions they may be subject to legal limitations but I am not familiar with these.

It seems like the relevant legal issues here would concern what police are and are not allowed to do with biological evidence and under what circumstances those samples can be released to third parties and what those third parties can do with it. I'm not trained in law and certainly not French law and I don't really think Academia.SE is the place to discuss either.

What I can speak to, though, is what sort of procedures would typically be followed in an academic research context in the US, where I work. All of that comes down to **the IRB decides**, but I can make a couple comments about how they'd go about those decisions:

1. Consent is not required for every study. In particular, consent is usually obtained to *collect* data. The most strict research subjects protection occurs when data collection impacts the subjects directly - for example, where a medication is given as part of the trial. In this case, there is no risk to the subjects in collecting the data: the samples are already collected for another purpose, which was not research-related. It's common in medical fields to do retrospective analyses from, say, patient health records. No informed consent is collected in these cases.
2. Even when data collection is not a risk, IRBs are still concerned with protecting research subjects. The primary concern is that release of data itself may somehow harm those subjects, whether through breach of their privacy or financial risks. Often these are mitigated by anonymizing the study, though IRBs will take care to ensure that data are truly anonymized, which in some cases may not be possible and may require further action like an unusual step to obtain consent. However, as far as I know IRBs are mostly/only concerned with *individual* harm. I don't believe IRBs typically consider *institutional* harm, such as to a sport, athletic organization, country, or hospital. To the contrary, a lot of data that are harmful or embarrassing to institutions are considered to have a lot of public value. Examples might be data that show evidence of racial or sex discrimination.

In this particular case, it seems that the study is missing a declaration that the work was reviewed by an appropriate ethical research authority. This seems to be against the journal's own policy, though the details of that policy are not made explicit. An IRB may have restricted how the data could be obtained or described, or they may not. I don't see a blatant violation here, though it does seem to me that the authors had a clear editorial intent to raise a controversy, as they could have easily published their main scientific findings without tying it explicitly to cycling.

Comment: Nice summary. I note that IRBs are required by the Federal government in order to get Federally sponsored research. Journals signed on voluntarily. These rules don't necessarily apply to anyone else.